# Grouping by Customer and concating products opened in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have some data that I'm wanting to use to determine what products every customer has opened. With this data, I'm wanting to either create a new column or multiple Columns indicating these products. For example, consider the data below.

```
CustomerKey ProductType
6458         Checking
6458         Savings
6458         Savings
6461         Savings
6461          IRA
```

For customer 6458, I'd either like to have a products column that concat his/her products like one of the ways below.

```
Customer     Products               Checking/Savings         Savings/IRA
6458         Checking/Savings                1                     0
6461         Savings/IRA                     0                     1
```

Is there anything I can use besides min/max around product type that will concat all of the members?

```
Select Customerkey, producttype
from share
group by customerkey
```

Comment: If you have access to a later version of SQL server you can use `STRING_AGG`

Comment: What's the logic for the other two columns? Eg what happens of a customer has checking and IRA?

Comment: Those output columns make no sense. Why do you need to name the columns with the contents of the Products output? Why not just have a column for each ProductType?

Comment: It would be the same as the others. It would either fall under products as "Checking/IRA" or I would create a column called Checking/IRA with an Indicator of 1. I would need to do columns for Checking/IRA/Savings, etc. I trimmed it down to make it a little easier.  Unfortunately, I tried String_AGG and it didn't work. I wish my company would let me use MYSQl so I could use groupconcat

Comment: Doing dynamic columns like that means you would have to use dynamic sql and it is a big red flag that something has gone wrong in the design here.

Comment: Having columns for each "maybe" combination of products is a serious anti-pattern - what happens if there are 10 products...? I would re-think this. The `Products` column is pretty easy.

Comment: Basically, my boss wants me to do some research on dormant members based on what products they have open (yes, he wants them segmented as I mentioned above) and wants me to look at balances, how many products they have (which I know I can do without the segments, years account open, etc).  Everything he wants I can easily do with basic SQL or python code, but he specifically wants them grouped and segmented as I mentioned.  Not saying it's a great idea by any means, but I'm certainly open to suggestions if there's a better way to go about it.

Comment: I would actually prefer just the products column but listed the other as an alternative option.

Comment: @user14316330 Realised you can use conditional aggregation provided you are prepared to hard-code the list of possible columns.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Simulating group\_concat MySQL function in Microsoft SQL Server 2005?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/451415/simulating-group-concat-mysql-function-in-microsoft-sql-server-2005)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do something like this. This is using STRING_AGG to generate the products list. And then some conditional aggregation across the known product types to have that column return a 1 or 0.

```
create table #Something
(
    CustomerKey int
    , ProductType varchar(20)
)
insert #Something
select 6458, 'Checking' union all
select 6458, 'Savings' union all
select 6458, 'Savings' union all
select 6461, 'Savings' union all
select 6461, 'IRA'
;

--using a cte to ensure we get only distinct ProductTypes
with PreAggregate as
(
    select distinct CustomerKey
        , ProductType
    from #Something
)

select s.CustomerKey
    , Products = STRING_AGG(ProductType, '/') within group(order by ProductType)
    , Checking = max(case when ProductType = 'Checking' then 1 else 0 end)
    , Savings = max(case when ProductType = 'Savings' then 1 else 0 end)
    , IRA = max(case when ProductType = 'IRA' then 1 else 0 end)
from PreAggregate s
group by s.CustomerKey

drop table #Something
```

Answer (score 2):

The logic for product combinations would require you to hard-code each possible combination into a conditional `sum` as below:

```
with p as (
    select distinct customerkey customer, Stuff(Products,1,1,'') Products
    from t
    cross apply (
        select distinct '/' + ProductType
        from t t2
        where t2.customerkey=t.customerkey
        for xml path('')
    )x(Products)
)
select *,
    max(case when products='Checking/Savings' then 1 else 0 end) as [Checking/Savings],
    max(case when products='IRA/Savings' then 1 else 0 end) as [IRA/Savings]
from p
group by customer, products
```